# What is the difference between babel.config.js and babel.build.config.js

Tags: javascript, babeljs

https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration - I have parsed through this document. It still doesn't answer my question though. When would I use `babel.config.js` versus `babel.build.config.js`?

Comment: Maybe it's used with https://babeljs.io/docs/en/options#configfile? Babel doesn't appear to use this file by itself. In which project did you find this?

Comment: Maybe. I just found it in some project that I was working on at my company. Maybe there is no significant difference

Comment: Then consider asking at your company, like the author of the project/config file.

Comment: ha, the author left, but let me ask someone else lol

Comment: Damn I think I figured out why that person did that. So the person can have 2 tsconfig configurations.